# Generating RSA keys with a specific public exponent

Tags: go, cryptography, rsa

The `crypto/rsa` library has the below function to generate a new RSA private key.

```
func GenerateKey(random io.Reader, bits int) (*PrivateKey, error)
```

This appears to default to use `65537` as the public exponent value. Is there an API I can use to generate a RSA private key with a public exponent of my choice that does not have a dependency on OpenSSL or another C library?

Comment: @tweaksp #1 That link is to a SHA-1 attack. That has nothing to do with RSA. #2 Attacks related to use of small exponents don't work when you use a proper padding mode. #3 I have many reasons for wanting to do this including but not limited to interop with other systems and writing testing tools.

Comment: Oops, accidently copied the wrong link! Fixing :)

Comment: Nope, the exponent is hardcoded in the generate function, and you can see the full public api documented here: https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/. The `GenerateMultiPrimeKey` function is self-contained, which you could copy into your source and modify if you want.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? 65537 is generally a good choice ... many attacks on RSA exploit small exponents, e.g. e=3.

Comment: @tweaksp There are no attacks against e=3 when you use proper padding. And when you use shitty padding, e=65537 doesn't completely prevent attacks, it only offers limited mitigation.

Comment: There's this attack on RSA-OAEP. It works if the coins have weak entropy: http://eprint.iacr.org/2005/189. I realize though that under ideal conditions, there are no attacks on RSA-OAEP with e=3.

Comment: public exponent is one of a couple of parameters, which are hidden by default implementation. E.g. I prefer to have public exponent chosen by random; then I want to decide over the minimum bit length difference of p and q, which is a security factor, finally for very large key sizes, I want to control the accuracy of parameters being prime, i.e. the depth of the rabin-miller test.

Short: I write my own RSA service with own parameter classes.

Answer (score 2):

You will not find such an API in Go.

This is because, for many reasons, 3 and 65537 match requirements needed for RSA to work and for RSA implementations to be fast.

Here are the explanations for these two properties:

- First, for RSA to work, the public exponent must be coprime with the cardinal number of the set of integers, between 1 and the modulus, that are coprime with the modulus (see RSA algorithm to understand why). So, choosing a prime number is a good way to have a chance for this number to be coprime with the cardinal number of the set described above, this is why people choose prime numbers as public exponents, most of the time (and if it is not the case, they compute a new modulus instead of changing the public exponent). Since the cardinal number of the set described above is even, you can not choose 2 (if the modulus is the product of primes p and q, this set has (p-1)(q-1) elements, that is obviously an even number).
- Moreover, for fast computation, the number of bits set to 1 in the binary representation of the public exponent must be lower as possible. 2 is the only prime number with one bit set to 1 in its binary representation. Since it can not be chosen, you will choose a prime number that only has 2 bits set to one in its binary representation. Therefore, the arithmetic product of such a prime with any other number only needs one addition and a logical shift left.

**The only known integers (up to now) that match these requirements are 3, 5, 17, 257 and 65537.**

Comment: Same question here, for some reason, I want it to be **17**, which happen to be one the **integers**, but we can't now (by using that function).

Comment: Most of the time, the public exponent values are hard coded in the libraries. This is the case for this API in Go. This explains you can not use 17.